# Free font and color chooser for WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, components

I'm looking for some good font chooser and color chooser components for WPF. I was trying to find some standard solutions like Winforms components but there seems to be none (I wonder why?).

It does not have to be perfect, someshing from code project would be enought but I would prefer good looking intuitive-to-use components.

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Look at [ColorPicker](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ColorPicker&referringTitle=Home) from [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)

[image] [image]

Comment: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/58768 - See link Extended WPF Toolkit Binaries